# Threadpool also uses a blocked thread to execute a new task from queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Sorry if question sounds so simple.

But I want to know that a thread pool only uses the finished threads to pick up new tasks or it can use a blocked thread also?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocked threads are blocked. Nothing can use them untill they become unblocked and return to the pool.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.